# Can anyone identify this frame?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I've recently picked up a 'beach cruiser' frame from a local free-add site. It was claimed to be a Huffy, however I can't seem to verify this (I've emailed Huffy and I'm awaiting their response, and in case it's not a Huffy I've posted here).

Frame Number is GH98142-- (Dashes represent last two escaped numbers), it looks like this: [image: this].

Comment: Pretty generic, but there are odd-looking lugs on the BB shell, and on both sides of the rear dropouts that someone might recognize.

Comment: I'm thinking the stuff on the left of the rear dropout is for a coaster brake. Right side maybe for a cable for internal hub gears?

Comment: Did you ever identify this frame?  Did you do anything with it in the last 3 years?

Answer (score 2):

Huffy isn't one of those bike companies that has a "nice" well-organized** history, especially in light of its more-recent history: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffy#Financial_problems So if it is a Huffy, no one at the company will likely be able to confirm it. Additionally, these weren't very (at all?) sought-after bikes so there won't be a user-group maintaining a serial number database (like some high-end brands).

** meaning not bought/sold/rebranded/in-name-only

Answer (score -1):

It looks a lot like my [Dyno Beach Cruiser](http://dynobicycles.info). Actually, I'm positive it is.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]! Please check out the [help] to learn how this site works, and in the meantime, use the shift key to stop SHOUTING.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider expanding your answer to explain what specifically makes you think this is a Dyno. While I'm not an expert in beach cruisers, the overall shape and design is fairly common to beach cruisers. A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Comment: The rear dropouts look very different to me.